# Cannot connect to local postgres database via pgAdmin4 (Mac)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have two databases running locally, I am able to connect to both via the psql command line, but when I attempt to connect to the second database, my unit test db, it throws a "Connection to server has been lost" error. I have no issues connecting to the development database via pgAdmin4.

Here is the console output:

```
$ psql 
  psql (9.6.4)
  Type "help" for help.

admin=# \c development
You are now connected to database "development" as user "admin".
development=# \c test
You are now connected to database "test" as user "admin".
test=#
```

[image: Here is the error displayed from pgAdmin4]

Comment: Did you check pgadmin4.log for any error?

Comment: @n33rma Yea, I just looked. There is no information about this issue in there.

Comment: Can you change the log level to debug in config_local.py and upload the log so that we can check for any error? Ref: https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#8